# javascript onsubmit event not triggering when form is submitted

Tags: javascript

```js
(function ($) {
    function additionalDetailsForm() {
        additional_info_flag = true;
        checkAdditionalInfoInput();
        return additional_info_flag;
    }
});
```

```html
<form method="POST" onsubmit="return additionalDetailsForm();"></form>
```

When I submit the form, it is directly going to *action.php*, and not triggering the `onsubmit` event.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Why did you wrap the function definition in `(function ($) { … }`?

Answer (score 0):

Unwrap your `additionalDetailsForm` from `(function ($) { ...` like below and then try.

What is happening is when you wrap `function` inside `(function ($) { ...` it will have scope limited to that `block`. And your `return additionalDetailsForm();` will try to find 
`additionalDetailsForm` function with global scope. So in your case it is not working.

```js
function additionalDetailsForm() {
  alert(1);
  additional_info_flag = true;
  checkAdditionalInfoInput();
  return additional_info_flag;
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" onsubmit="return additionalDetailsForm();">
  <button type='submit'>submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the jquery method and others in following way:-

```js
     $(function() {
            console.log( "ready!" );
         $( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
               
                var additional_info_flag = true;
                checkAdditionalInfoInput();
                console.log(additional_info_flag);
                return additional_info_flag;
                
                event.preventDefault();
           });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<form id="target" action="destination.html">
  <input type="text" value="Hello there">
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues:

1. You're wrapping your function in another, anonymous function. That means your function will be defined in the scope of the anonymous function and won't be available globally. Remove the `(function ($) { ... })` surrounding your function.
2. Your function always returns `true`, which means the form will always be submitted. If you don't want that to happen, you want to either return `false` from that function or prevent the form submission event from triggering.

So your code could be changed to:

```js
function additionalDetailsForm() {
    let additional_info_flag = false;
    checkAdditionalInfoInput();

    // return false, to prevent the form from being submitted
    return additional_info_flag;
}
```

Or, if you never want the form to be submitted:

```js
function additionalDetailsForm(event) {
    // prevent the form from being submitted by preventing
    // the submission event from triggering
    event.preventDefault();

    checkAdditionalInfoInput();
}
```